# Using React Navigation, how can I render the back button on an outer stack header based on the screen of a nested stack?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

Here's a snack which demonstrates the problem: https://snack.expo.io/@zeckdude/navigation-demo

I am nesting stacks inside a drawer navigator, while the drawer navigator is nested inside a stack navigator.

I am using the outer stack navigator to display a header bar with a logo in the middle and a menu button on the left, which toggles the menu. I would like for the drawer toggle button to be replaced with a back button whenever one of the nested stacks inside the drawer are on the 2nd or greater page in their stack.

How can I render the back button on an outer stack header based on the screen of a nested stack?

```
/**
 * Authorized Drawer
 * Used to set the labels in the drawer and enable drawer
 */
const AuthorizedDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    ScanQR: {
      screen: ScanQRScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: 'Scan'
      } 
    },
    ItemStack: { 
      screen: ItemStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: 'Items'
      } 
    },
    SendStack: { 
      screen: SendStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: 'Send'
      } 
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'ItemStack'
  }
);


/**
 * Authorized Drawer Stack
 * Put the drawer inside a stack so the header can be added and styled
 */
const AuthorizedDrawerStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    AuthorizedDrawer: { screen: AuthorizedDrawer },
  }, 
  {
    headerMode: 'float',
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
      return {
        headerLeft: (
          <View 
            style={{
              paddingLeft: 10,
            }}
          >
            <Icon 
              name={navigation.state.isDrawerOpen ? 'close' : 'menu'} 
              color="#2F6BAE"
              onPress={() => {
                navigation.toggleDrawer();
              }} 
            />
          </View>
        ),
        headerTitle: <Logo />
      };
    }
  }
)


/**
 * Root Stack
 * Contains all the stacks so you can link from links within one stack to links in the other stack
 */
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    OnboardingStack: { screen: OnboardingStack },
    AuthorizedStack: { screen: AuthorizedDrawerStack },
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none'
  }
);
```

Comment: What i did was hook up the <Logo/> component with redux .. and handles things based on redux state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just had to add a small condition inside `navigationOptions` of `AuthorizedDrawerStack`

```
import { HeaderBackButton } from 'react-navigation';

let isRootScreen = (navigation) => navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index].index === 0;

const AuthorizedDrawerStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        AuthorizedDrawer: { screen: AuthorizedDrawer },
    },
    {
        headerMode: 'float',
        navigationOptions: ({navigation, screenProps, navigationOptions}) => {
            return {
                headerLeft: (
                    <View
                        style={{
                            paddingLeft: 10,
                        }}>
                        {isRootScreen(navigation) ?  // <-- HERE
                            <Icon
                                name={navigation.state.isDrawerOpen ? 'close' : 'menu'}
                                color="#2F6BAE"
                                onPress={() => {
                                    navigation.toggleDrawer();
                                }}
                            />
                         : <HeaderBackButton onPress={() => navigation.goBack(null)} />}
                    </View>
                ),
                headerTitle: <Logo />
            };
        }
    }
)
```

Here's the working [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@lasitha/navigation-demo).